# IF condition in MYsql not giving proper result

Tags: mysql

This is code of  mysql stored procedure:

```
BEGIN
DECLARE sms INT(100);
SET sms=(SELECT COUNT(1) FROM tbl_intofone_alert_transaction WHERE smsid='sms_id');
IF(sms<=>0) THEN
INSERT INTO tbl_intofone_alert_transaction(MSISDN,Message,Tag,SenderID,InTime,deliverystatus,
memberid,smsid,updatetime,submit_type,wu_id,DeviceID) 
VALUES(mob,msg,tag,sender,NOW(),'0',memid,sms_id,NOW(),'NULL','NULL',DevId);
END IF;
   END$$
```

**IF CONDITION** in above code doing insertion for all the cases . what i have done wrong here?

Comment: Which cases of sms do you want to accept ?

Comment: Well, what happens if you just run the first `SELECT` manually? And is it possible that `sms` is ever `NULL`?

Comment: it gives required result

Comment: @Ekansh Really? Because `smsid` doesn't sound like a column that can contain a string.

Comment: Why you don't use the solution provided here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3164505/mysql-insert-record-if-not-exists-in-table It is much cleaner and does not require a variable.

Comment: @Jack sorry i have found what was the problem actually . (1) i have assigned variable "sms_id" as string and (2) in the "IF statement" use of operator <=> it must be <=. thanx for pointimg that..

Comment: @Ekansh: Actually both `<=> 0` and `<= 0` will work fine, but isn't it much simpler to just use `= 0` to test for equality with zero? It seems like you are trying random operators until it works instead of thinking about how to solve the problem.

Comment: thank you @MarkByers , i have use "=" as per my requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it must be

```
   IF(sms<=0) THEN    //sms  less then or equal 0
```

or

```
  IF(sms>=0) THEN      //sms  bigger then or equal 0
```

`<=>` this is not comparaison in mysql

obs

```
  VALUES(mob,msg,tag,sender,NOW(),'0',memid,sms_id,NOW(),'NULL','NULL',DevId);
```

most of those values i dont know what they are , they looks wrong

they must be variables that u get them from your code.

in this code there is only `NOW()` and `NULL` which are right

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that you want to search for the string literal `'sms_id'` here?

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM tbl_intofone_alert_transaction WHERE smsid='sms_id'
```

Probably you meant to use the value of the `sms_id` variable:

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM tbl_intofone_alert_transaction WHERE smsid = sms_id
```

Comment: This one right: SELECT COUNT(1) FROM tbl_intofone_alert_transaction WHERE smsid='42'

Comment: Try `sms_id` (without the quotes).