# Why doesn't this IF NOT EXISTS statement work?

Tags: mysql, sql, if-statement, exists

I'm trying to write a query which will INSERT a random value between 0 to 9999 INTO a table, whereas this random value is yet to exist there.
However, nothing I wrote works. It seems like a WHERE clause doesn't work with INSERT, and my SQL server fails to execute an IF NOT EXISTS query. Is it incorrect, I wonder?
What should I do? Is there a solution to my problem?
(I'm using MySQL)

```
SET @rand = ROUND(RAND() * 9999);
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT `num` FROM `nums` WHERE `num` = @rand)
    INSERT INTO `nums` (`num`) VALUES (@rand);
```

Comment: MySQL or Oracle? They're completely different.

Comment: IF statements like that only work in things like TSQL and PL/SQL.  If you are just executing a query, that isn't going to work.  You will have to put that logic into your executing code.

Comment: How do I do that? I'm using the MySQL version that is used with the current version of WampServer and XAMPP.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like here: [MySQL: Insert record if not exists in table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3164505/mysql-insert-record-if-not-exists-in-table)

```
INSERT INTO `nums` (`num`)
SELECT *
FROM
  (SELECT @rand) AS q
WHERE NOT EXISTS
    (SELECT `num`
     FROM `nums`
     WHERE `num` = @rand);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it using a stored procedure like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE my_sp()
BEGIN
SET @rand = ROUND(RAND() * 9999);
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT `num` FROM `nums` WHERE `num` = @rand) THEN
    INSERT INTO `nums` (`num`) VALUES (@rand);
END IF;
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Using statements like `IF` belongs inside a block of code like a stored procedure.  You won't be able to execute it just on the mysql prompt.

If you just want to insert the a random value that wasn't there before you can also do it by

```
mysql> create table nums(num int, unique key(num));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.05 sec)

mysql> insert ignore into nums >select round(rand()*9999);>
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 >sec)>
Records: 1  Duplicates: 0  Warn>ings>: 0>

mysql> insert ignore into nums select round(rand()*9999);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 1  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> insert ignore into nums select round(rand()*9999);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 1  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> insert ignore into nums select round(rand()*9999);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 1  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from nums;
+------+
| num  |
+------+
| 5268 |
| 9075 |
| 9114 |
| 9768 |
+------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

With `insert ignore`, it won't insert a row if it already exists.