# Conditional INSERT INTO MySQL - WHERE NOT EXISTS

Tags: php, mysql, sql-insert

I am trying to do an INSERT INTO query when the customer does not already have a record of purchasing a product.

I have tried the below SQL, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
$queryAddPurchase = "INSERT INTO purchase (UserID, Product, Price) 
              VALUES ('$userID', '$product', '$price')
              WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT Product
                                       FROM purchase
                       WHERE Product = '$product'
                       AND UserID = '$userID')";
```

The error I am receiving is as follows:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT Product FROM purchase ' at line 3

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: what do mean when you say its not working?

Comment: You could set up `UserID` and `Product` as a unique key and then use one of `INSERT IGNORE`, `REPLACE INTO` or `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`.

Comment: I am receiving the below error:

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT Product FROM purchase ' at line 3

Comment: put the error in your question

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15622121/mysql-query-insert-where-not-exists

Comment: @AshReva which is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3164505/mysql-insert-record-if-not-exists-in-table

Answer (score 1):

On the assumption, that a user may only buy one of each product (ever and for all products).

```
ALTER TABLE purchase ADD UNIQUE KEY (`UserID`, `Product`); -- run this just once. this changes the table

INSERT IGNORE INTO purchase (UserID, Product, Price) VALUES ('$userID', '$product', '$price');
```

Be aware, that this then prevents him from buying any product multiple times, which might not be the desired outcome.

Answer (score 1):

If possible, add a UNIQUE constraint to the table. Something like ...

```
alter table purchase add unique user_product (UserID, ProductID);
```

And your conditional insert becomes trivial:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO purchase (UserID, Product, Price) 
    VALUES ('$userID', '$product', '$price')
```

If this is *not* a suitable solution for you, use the selected answer here: [MySQL Conditional Insert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/913841/mysql-conditional-insert)

That answer, in brief:

```
INSERT INTO purchase (UserID, Product, Price) 
    SELECT '$userID', '$product', '$price'
    FROM dual
        WHERE NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT * FROM purchase
            WHERE UserID='$userID'
                AND ProductID='$product'
        )
```

Comment: And I should mention, this is *probably* ideal if your schema allows for it, because you'll likely want those columns indexed for the lookup anyway.

Comment: mysql does not allow that. *on the alternative*

Comment: @scones Are you sure? The commenters on the selected answer seem to attest that it works ...

Comment: @swidgen found my mistake, the answer there is correct. works by the magic of `dual`. +1 for you :)

Comment: @scones Just tested on MySQL 5.1. It works. `insert into states (name) select 'Wisconsin' from dual where not exists (select name from states where name='Wisconsin');`