# Lock "local" MySQL table

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to do the same thing as described in [MySQL: Insert record if not exists in table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3164505/mysql-insert-record-if-not-exists-in-table), but I'm running it on command line so I need to lock tables manually. This is what I have:

```sql
LOCK TABLES `mytable` WRITE;
INSERT INTO `mytable` (`mycolumn`)
SELECT * FROM (SELECT 'test') AS temp
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( 
  SELECT `mycolumn`
  FROM `mytable`
  WHERE `mycolumn` = 'test'
) LIMIT 1;
UNLOCK TABLES;
```

However, when I run this I get the error:

```
ERROR 1100 (HY000) at line 239: Table 'mytable' was not locked with LOCK TABLES
```

The command executes fine without lock/unlock in MySQL Workbench. My guess is that I need to lock the "temp" table, but how do I do that??

```
LOCK TABLES `mytable` WRITE, <something> AS temp WRITE;
```

Since "temp" is not an actual table in the database, it's just (SELECT 'test').

I can add that the reason why I don't (just) want to create a unique index is that this results in an error that I don't know how to handle since the exit code for the command line process is always just 1 in case of an error and I really don't want to parse stderr for it...

Comment: Is `mytable` by any chance a temporary table ?  Post the output of: show create table `mytable`;

Comment: mytable, CREATE TABLE `mytable` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `value` varchar(10) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=82 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_swedish_ci

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior is well documented in the MySQL manual page for LOCK TABLES;

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/lock-tables.html

> You cannot refer to a locked table multiple times in a single query
>   using the same name. Use aliases instead, and obtain a separate lock
>   for the table and each alias:

So, this should work for you:

```
LOCK TABLES `mytable` WRITE, `mytable` as m2 READ
INSERT INTO `mytable` (`value`) SELECT * FROM (SELECT 'test') AS temp
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( 
  SELECT `value`
  FROM `mytable` as `m2`
  WHERE `value` = 'test'
) LIMIT 1;
UNLOCK TABLES;
```