# MySQL - "insert if not exists" query?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to write a MySQL query which will update a blog post view counter if the user has not visited the post in the last 24 hours. I'm trying to write something like this (but this does not work):

```
  IF EXISTS (
     SELECT 1
     FROM `posts-views`
     WHERE
        `ip` = '".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."'
        AND
        `time` > ".($time-60*60*24)."
        AND
        `post` = $id
  ) THEN
  NULL

  ELSE

  INSERT INTO `posts-views`
  (`post`, `time`, `ip`, `user`)
  VALUES
  ($id, $time, '".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."', $me)
```

What's the correct way to fix the query?

Comment: you can use `insert ignore` - it will insert or just pass without error if row with duplicate keys exists, also it has nice feature `on duplicate key update`

Comment: I have no idea how to use INSERT IGNORE in this case. I'm not inserting the same data. The time may differ.

Comment: you can, if you add new column with only date part (user will be able to vote 1 time per day)

Comment: `Insert ignore` requires unique key, which I don't think is possible to create in this case because of condition on `time` : `time > ....` .

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3164505/mysql-insert-record-if-not-exists-in-table 

this link may help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I see you cannot use `INSERT IGNORE` in that case, but something like following should do the job :

```
  INSERT INTO `posts-views`
  (`post`, `time`, `ip`, `user`)
  SELECT $id, $time, '".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."', $me 
  FROM dual 
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (
     SELECT 1
     FROM `posts-views`
     WHERE
    `ip` = '".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."'
      AND
    `time` > ".$time-60*60*24."
    AND
    `post` = $id
  )
```

I completely omit escaping variables which definitely should be done in real code.

**UPDATED** - added `from dual` to avoid syntax error

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM `posts-views` WHERE ' at line 6

Comment: @Richard Rodriguez : check updated version, it should be good