# "if not exists" SQL Statement Giving Error

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have the following sql query running and it is giving me error 1064, syntax error.

```
IF NOT EXISTS (select * from locations where STREET_ADDRESS = 'test') 
BEGIN
    insert into locations (STREET_ADDRESS) values ('test') 
end;
```

Can someone please help me out? It seems so simple yet it will not run. Thanks.

Also, I'm running MySQL version 5.6.11

Comment: values, where, from, select, inset, into  must be Upper try it

Comment: @user3173819 No; MySql is case-insensitive, at least my version is. Thank you for the suggestion though.

Comment: you should follow this link as “if not exists”


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3164741/3242978

Answer (score 0):

Also you can try this

```
INSERT INTO locations (STREET_ADDRESS)
SELECT 'test' FROM DUAL
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT * from locations where STREET_ADDRESS = 'test'
) LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
IF ((select * from locations where STREET_ADDRESS = 'test')=0 )
BEGIN
insert into locations (STREET_ADDRESS) values ('test') 
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use this type of sample code as:

```
   INSERT INTO table_listnames (name, address, tele)
    SELECT * FROM (SELECT 'Rupert', 'Somewhere', '022') AS tmp
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT name FROM table_listnames WHERE name = 'Rupert'
    ) LIMIT 1;
```

[***click here***](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3164741/3242978)