# IF NOT EXISTS query used to insert new rows throws error

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to use this query to insert the value `kyckling` into column `Produkter` and `Sallader` into column `typ`, but I get an error around `IF NOT EXISTS`:

```
BEGIN
    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
                   FROM innehall
                   WHERE Produkter = 'kyckling'
                     AND typ = 'Sallader')
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO innehall (Produkter, typ)
        VALUES ('kyckling', 'Sallader')
    END
END;
```

Comment: Hey, check these: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3164505/mysql-insert-record-if-not-exists-in-table & https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22290130/if-not-exists-sql-statement-giving-error

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that control-flow logic such as the `IF` statement (NOT `if()` the function) is allowed only in programming blocks -- stored procedures, functions, and trigger.

You can do what you want with a query such as:

```
INSERT INTO innehall (Produkter, typ)
    SELECT Produkter, typ
    FROM (SELECT 'kyckling' as Produkter, 'Sallader' as typ) x
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                      FROM innehall i
                      WHERE i.Produkter = x.Produkter AND i.typ = x.typ
                     );
```

But the better approach is to let the database ensure uniqueness rather than you having to do this.  So:

```
alter table innehall add constraint unq_innehall_produkter_typ
    unique (produkter, typ);
```

And then phrase the insert like this:

```
insert into innehall (produkter, typ)
    values (kyckling', 'Sallader')
    on duplicate key update typ = values(typ);
```

This attempts the update.  If the unique constraint is violated, then it ignores the error.