# MySQL insert if table not exists

Tags: mysql, insert, not-exists

I'll tried creating a little installation script for my modules.
When I call `$_GET["install"]` the script is running. I looks like this:

```
public function install()
{
  $this->sql->query("
    INSERT
    INTO    cms_modules (title)
    VALUES  ('Guestbook')
  ");

  $this->sql->query("
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cms_guestbook` (
      `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    ) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
  ");
}
```

It works pretty good. The table is installed and a new row is added to `cms_modules`, although I would like that the INSERT is only activated if the `cms_guestbook` table **doesn't** exists.

I searched for a answer and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3164505/mysql-insert-record-if-not-exists-in-table) topic. I'll tried using that `WHERE NOT EXISTS` by doing the following:

```
$this->sql->query("
  INSERT
  INTO    cms_modules (title)
  VALUES  ('Guestbook')
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (
          SELECT 1 FROM cms_guestbook
  )
");
```

But this didn't worked for my. The table is installed, but the row not inserted. I also tried using `SHOW TABLES LIKE` but that also didn't seem to work.

Anyone suggestions or a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
if(!$this->sql->query("SHOW TABLES LIKE 'cms_guestbook'")){
    $this->sql->query("
        INSERT
        INTO    cms_modules (title)
        VALUES  ('Guestbook')
      ");
}
```

You query to see if it finds a specific table and if it returns false (check to be sure it returns a boolean) you run your other query.