# SQL if not exists

Tags: mysql, sql, if-statement

I have a **SQL** syntax error with my `IF NOT EXISTS` on line 1 when I tried to do this request on **MySQL**, and I can't figure why.

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM `my_table` WHERE first_name = 'Testfn')
BEGIN
INSERT INTO `my_table` (first_name)
VALUES ('Testfn')
END;
```

I'm trying to insert first_name only if there is no other same first name in my_table.

I also tried this syntax, but I still have the error 1064 "You have an error in your SQL syntax" :

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM `my_table` WHERE first_name = 'Testfn') THEN
INSERT INTO `my_table` (first_name)
VALUES ('Testfn')
END IF;
```

I tried `SELECT * FROM`my_table`WHERE first_name = 'Testfn'` separately, and it works.

And like this doesn't work too :

```
INSERT INTO `my_table` (first_name)
VALUES ('Testfn')
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM `my_table` WHERE first_name = 'Testfn');
```

EDIT : first_name is UNIQUE in the database.

Comment: I think you can see from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361340/how-to-insert-if-not-exists-in-mysql

Comment: please mention your actual table name,cause syntax seems to be correct.Also mention error that you are getting.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3164505/mysql-insert-record-if-not-exists-in-table

Comment: Have you read the manual on the MySQL IF statement (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/if.html)? The syntax is as follows: IF [condition] THEN [command] END IF;

Comment: @TimBurch : I tested with this syntax, but still I have a syntax error.

Comment: Will you please post the exact SQL you used and the error message you receive.

Answer (score 0):

You have not need to write a column name, without specifying you can try to insert because we already checked condition on above. So basically you can do it using **[Merge Statement](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_9016.htm)** like.

```
MERGE INTO my_table
USING ( 
   SELECT first_name
) t
ON t.first_name = my_table.first_name
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
INSERT (first_name) VALUES (t.first_name);
```

Hope this help you!

Comment: May be I am didnt get it. But what is `users` in your query?

Comment: sorry its my mistaken.

Comment: Also to add that your first query is not different from what OP posted. That would not work!

Comment: Double check i'm suggest to remove column name (first_name).

Comment: That would not create any difference if the user has only one column. Infact it is necessary if the table has more than one column. Your first query is wrong!

Comment: i think OP's got solution. and as per ur suggest i remove first query. Now you can check merge query work or not and give me reply. because i m tested.