# Insert only if new value is the highest

Tags: mysql

Player 1 has finished a game and got a score of 10. We should save this score only if it's the high score for that user. How could I accomplish this in a single query?
I tried this:

```
INSERT INTO highscore("score", "player") values(10, 1)
WHERE (SELECT MAX(score) as hs FROM highscore WHERE player = 1) < 10;
```

Thanks

Comment: I've already read that. However I don't know what that "select 2, 20" is for?

Comment: `select 2, 20` -- that is selecting 2 columns with the values of 2 and 20 respectively.  In your case, `select 10, 1` would be equivalent, where the first column is the score and the second is the player.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ugly thing is that mysql does not support insert into values with where condition, but you can cheat by doing this:

```
INSERT INTO highscore (score, player)
SELECT 10, 1 FROM dual
WHERE (SELECT max(score) FROM highscore WHERE player = 1) < 10
```

This will insert no rows if the score is higher than 10, otherwise it will create a row with the values you need. It's also easier than a trigger and i believe it also has a lower cost.

Answer (score 0):

Make uniq index on player. Then make insert update statement with Max () function. This can help if you are using mysql.

something like this:
Alter table highscore add uniq key (player);
Insert into highscore (player, score) values (1,10) 
on duplicate update
Score = max (score,10)

Comment: But this replaces the last high score. I want to have a history of highscores. Im working on a solution with a trigger function before insert. It might work.

Comment: 1. why you need it on a single query?
2. why don't you create a procedure instead of a trigger?

Comment: Trigger is solution. Becareful if you are using replication.

Comment: 1. To lower the costs. 
2.I can't use procedure because the hosting provider does not allow it.

Comment: Insert into highscore (player, score) values (1,10) on duplicate update Score = max (Score,10), history = concat (history,',', Score). But in single query it is realy difficult or stupid :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO `max_score` 
  SELECT 77, 7 FROM `max_score` WHERE NOT EXISTS 
  (SELECT * FROM `max_score` WHERE id = 77 AND score >= 7) LIMIT 1;
```

(`77` is the `id`, and `7` is the `score`.)

This will insert if there are no values greater than or equal to 7 with and id equal to 77, and will NOT insert if there are values greater than 7.

And with prepared statements and a timestamp:

```
<?php

$id = 77;
$score = 13;

$date = new DateTime();
$timestamp = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

$sql = <<<EOT

INSERT INTO `max_score` 
  SELECT ?, ?, ? FROM `max_score` WHERE NOT EXISTS 
  (SELECT * FROM `max_score` WHERE id = ? AND score >= ?) LIMIT 1;

EOT;

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param('iisii', $id, $score, $timestamp, $id, $score);
$stmt->execute();

?>
```

(One caveat: table `max_score` must have at least one record in it for the `SELECT ?, ? FROM`max_score` to return the provided values.)

Inspired by: [MySQL: Insert record if not exists in table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3164505/mysql-insert-record-if-not-exists-in-table)