# mysql batch insert with where clause

Tags: mysql

I would like to modify the following code to do a "batch" insert and using a where clause with values provided in the array..

Code is taken from the provided link : [MySQL: Insert record if not exists in table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3164505/mysql-insert-record-if-not-exists-in-table)

```
INSERT INTO table_listnames (name, address, tele)
VALUES ('Rupert', 'Somewhere', '022')
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT name FROM table_listnames WHERE name='value'
);
```

Comment: Have you any error and what you want?

Comment: I don't know how to modify the where clause for batching purposes

Comment: The INSERT doesn't support the WHERE clause (as given in an answer in the item you linked to). INSTEAD OF VALUES... you can use a SELECT and within that check the WHERE. Can you give a few more details of the batch and the array, and how the value to check relates to the values being inserted?