# Query error INSERT if not exist

Tags: mysql

Hi this might be an easy question.
but after trying multiple things i gave up.

Cant see what is wrong with this query:

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT email FROM gebr_tickets WHERE email ='test@test.nl' ) 
INSERT INTO gebr_tickets (name,gebr_name, password, email, RelatieID) 
VALUES ('k','k','cmmNkftA','test@test.nl',170)
```

the error is :

> [Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT email FROM gebr_tickets WHERE email ='test@test.nl' ) INSERT INTO'

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3164505/mysql-insert-record-if-not-exists-in-table

this link maybe help you to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the below code for ignoring duplicate records

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO gebr_tickets (name,gebr_name, password, email, RelatieID) 
VALUES ('k','k','cmmNkftA','test@test.nl',170);
```

Comment: it will still insert it

Answer (score 0):

Simplest approach would be

```
INSERT INTO gebr_tickets (NAME,gebr_name, PASSWORD, email, RelatieID) 
SELECT 'k','k','cmmNkftA','test@test.nl',170 FROM DUAL 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT email FROM gebr_tickets WHERE email ='test@test.nl' )
```

This is another way .

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `sp_insert` ()
BEGIN
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT email FROM gebr_tickets WHERE email ='test@test.nl' )
THEN


INSERT INTO gebr_tickets (name,gebr_name, password, email, RelatieID) 
VALUES ('k','k','cmmNkftA','test@test.nl',170);


END IF;

END$$
DELIMITER ; 

CALL sp_insert(); 

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `sp_insert`;
```

Comment: this will insert multiple times?

Comment: No. Only once. Try this and see

Comment: yeah in navicat it inserts multiple times XD

Comment: Tried the first approach?

Comment: yes its in a sprintf condition so that would be the best way

Answer (score 0):

You can't use control statements like `IF` outside of procedures/functions/triggers. You need a shell around that.