# Prevent Duplicate Insert

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, insert

I have a page which is doing an insert.  The DB table has a unique column called "order" that auto increments upon adding a new row.  I am executing the insert in this way:

```
$insert = <<<SQL
INSERT INTO `order` (name, email, team, project, startdate, enddate, comment, server) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?);
SQL;
$instat = $mysqli->prepare($insert);
$bind = mysqli_stmt_bind_param($instat, "ssssssss", $name, $email, $team, $project, $timestart, $timeend, $comment, $code);
$exec = mysqli_stmt_execute($instat);
mysqli_stmt_close($instat);
mysqli_close($mysqli);
```

I am allowing the DB to handle an auto increment of the order column so that it cannot be duplicated.  This works just fine, but if I were to hit refresh on the page, it will insert another row with the same data on a new unique order id.  How can I prevent another insert upon a page refresh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After saving the row, redirect the page to another page with corresponding message . Your flow will be like

```
  1) $service->saveObject($dataObject);
  2) redirect_to_success page.
```

Comment: How do I carry over the ID that is generated after the insert so that I can query it and display it on the success page?

Comment: redirect_to_success.php?id=$yourId

Comment: Thanks.  I am using mysqli_insert_id() to get the order id and pass that to the "success" page.  Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

1. before every insert - make select query and check
2. Make insert query with NOT EXIST:

   - [How to 'insert if not exists' in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361340/how-to-insert-if-not-exists-in-mysql)
   - [MySQL: Insert record if not exists in table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3164505/mysql-insert-record-if-not-exists-in-table)

3.Redirect to current page after insert.