# preventing duplicate row insertion in mysql while importing csv file

Tags: php, mysql, csv

Preventing duplicate row insertion in `mysql` while importing `csv file`.I want to insert data into mysql table via importing csv file. how to prevent `duplicate row` insert?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3164505/mysql-insert-record-if-not-exists-in-table

Comment: i am inserting data to mysql via import CSV file

Answer (score 2):

Create an UNIQUE index in the column which might have dups, then

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'file.csv' IGNORE INTO TABLE table_name
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"'
ESCAPED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

Comment: i dont have good knowledge in php mysql sir, if u dont mind can u explain clearly please. thank u.

Comment: the column which you think has duplicates create an unique key index on that. go to mysql terminal alter the  table which you have command would be " alter table table name add unique index `index name` `column name`; https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html then use the LOAD data infile csv on the table