# Node.js async order

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, request, cheerio

While I was using async module and bookshelf.js orm, duplicate records (person roles) are being added to the database even though I check before adding them, I couldn't figure out why.

In a nutshell, here's what I'm trying to achieve.

- Visit some urls (in parallel, it's a web scraper, it visits 10 urls each time thanks to http.globalAgent.maxSockets), fetch `person id`, `person name` and `roles`.
- If a person exists in the database (I check it using the person id, it's the same id that I fetch from the a url), add him/her. If the record exists, don't do anything.
- Get the names of the roles of this person and query the database. If the role doesn't exist in the database, add it first, get its id, then add it to the pivot table (many-to-many relationship since a person can have more than one roles) If the role exists, just add it to the pivot table with related person_id.

I'm using `async`, `request`, `cheerio` and `bookshelf.js`.

```
app.get('/async', function (req, res) {

  var urlArr = [];
  for (var i = 10; i < 100; i++) {
    urlArr.push("http://www.example.com/person/" + i + "/personname.html");
  }
  async.each(urlArr, function (url, callback) {
      request({
        url: url,
        headers: {
          'User-Agent': req.headers['user-agent'],
          'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
        }
      }, function (err, resp, body) {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
        } else {
          if (cheerio.load(body)) {
            var $ = cheerio.load(body);
            var links = $('#container');
            var name = links.find('span[itemprop="name"]').html(); // name
            if (name == null) {
              console.log("null returned, do nothing");
            } else {
              name = entities.decodeHTML(name);
              var r = url.substring(33, 35);
              person.where('id', r).fetch({require: true}).then(function (p) {
                // person exists, don't do anything
              }).catch(function () {
                // person doesn't exist, proceed
                var numberOfRoles = links.find('span[itemprop="roletitle"]').length; // number of roles
                new person({id: r, name: name}).save(null, {method: 'insert'}).then(function (returnval) {
                  var rolesArr = [];
                  for (var b = 0; b < numberOfRoles; b++) {
                    rolesArr.push(b);
                  }
                  async.each(rolesArr, function (roles, callback) {
                    var personTypes = $('span[itemprop="roletitle"]').eq(roles).text();
                    var personTypes = entities.decodeHTML(personTypes);

                    personRole.where('role', personTypes).fetch().then(function (data1) {
                      // role exists, add the role_id and person_id to the pivot table
                      new personPersonRole({
                        person_id: r,
                        personrole_id: data1.id
                      }).save().then(function (data2) {
                        console.log("role has been added");
                      });
                    }).catch(function () {
                      // role doesn't exist, add it first
                      new personRole({
                        role: personTypes
                      }).save().then(function (data3) {
                        console.log("new added role_id is : " + data3.id);
                        // add person_id and role_id to the pivot table
                        new personPersonRole({
                          person_id: r,
                          personrole_id: data3.id
                        }).save();
                      });
                    });
                    callback();
                  });
                });
              });
            }
          }
          else {
            console.log("can't open");
          }
        }
      });
      callback();
    },
    function (err) {
      if (err) {
        console.log("err");
      } else {
        console.log("success");
      }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the common issue in multithreaded or asynchronous programming. What is likely happening is this:

- Scraper is told to scrape URL A
- Scraper is told to scrape URL B
- ...
- Ask whether role X from URL A exists
- Ask whether role X from URL B exists
- Time passes; MySQL determines that X does not exist, fires callback to URL A handler
- Time passes; MySQL determines that X does not exist (again), fires callback to URL B handler
- URL A handler's callback pops off the event queue; Tell MySQL to make role X for URL A
- URL B handler's callback pops off the event queue; Tell MySQL to make role X for URL B

What you need to do is pretty simple: make role names `UNIQUE` in your database. This will not prevent the code from trying to create the role twice, but it will make it fail each time but once. Then don't check whether or not the role exists; just try to create it each time.

Alternately, there is a [clever trick with SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3164505/mysql-insert-record-if-not-exists-in-table) where you can insert something if it doesn't exist. It may or may not work with bookshelf, but I am not brave enough to try.