# PHP - Skip if already exists

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, compare

I have been comparing 2 tables using JOIN and storing my result in another table called `macadd`. Each time I run my code its generating duplicate record in table `macadd`. How I can stop same record being stored again and again. 
Here is code which is generating duplicates:

```
$query = mysqli_query($conn, "insert into macadd (mac)
select volley.mac from volley
inner join savedemail on savedemail.email = volley.email");
```

As This query is comparing the rows. I am completely out of logic here that how can I make a variable out of this sql query. So that using that I can check weather record exist or not

Comment: Do you want insert if not exists? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3164505/mysql-insert-record-if-not-exists-in-table

Comment: Yes! ofcourse i want to insert if not exists

Comment: i am not able to use `(mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0)` here because there is no variable through which I can validate it,

Comment: you need slice your query to 2 other query. The first you check exists, and if not exist you run the second query : `insert`

Answer (score 0):

You want to use INSERT IGNORE.

```
$query = mysqli_query($conn, "insert ignore into macadd (mac)
select volley.mac from volley
inner join savedemail on savedemail.email = volley.email");
```

Comment: Does MySql have such expression? I know of "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE" or "INSERT ..WHERE NOT EXISTS(....)", never heard of that

Comment: @jim its not working even not inserting records

Comment: @shreyash-singh Sorry I meant INSERT IGNORE. I have updated my answer.