# sql syntax error from my query

Tags: java, mysql

I'm recently developing database api using java, vertx, gradle and mysql. I think I made a correct query but it shows me an error. Anybody knows the problem? Thanks in advance.

Query :

```
INSERT INTO USER VALUES('test@test.co.kr', 'test', 'password')
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM USER WHERE email='test@test.co.kr')
```

Error :

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM USER WHERE email='test@test.co.kr')' at line 1
```

Comment: `IF NOT EXISTS` is not in your posted query.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL: Insert record if not exists in table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3164505/mysql-insert-record-if-not-exists-in-table)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should do it like this:

```
INSERT INTO USER
SELECT 'test@test.co.kr', 'test', 'password'
FROM DUAL
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM USER WHERE email='test@test.co.kr')
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe you should mention column names after INSERT INTO USER .

Something like this;

```
INSERT INTO USER (email, username, password)
VALUES('test@test.co.kr', 'test', 'password') 
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
(SELECT * FROM USER WHERE email='test@test.co.kr')
```

Comment: It's been a long time to use sql so I forgot alot :(
Thank you so much for reminding me!!