# Download xlsx from S3 and parse it

Tags: node.js, excel, express

I need a service to download an excel file from Amazon S3, then parse with [node-xlsx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-xlsx)

The problem is that I can't get xlsx to parse the file. When I try to read back the file I just wrote, it isn't found by the code.

I'm not quite sure if this is the best approach, but this is what I got so far:

```
router.get('/process', (req, res) => {
    var fileName = 'https://some-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/some-excel-file.xlsx'
    https.get(fileName, response => {
        var body = ''
        response.on('data', chunk => body += chunk)
        response.on('end', () => {

            //fs is being imported early on this file
            fs.writeFile(__dirname + '/test.xlsx', body)

            var f = fs.createReadStream(__dirname + '/test.xlsx')

            var book = xlsx.parse(f)
            book.forEach(sheet => console.log('sheet', sheet.name) )

            res.status(200)          
        })
        .on('error', e => {
            res.status(500)
        })
    })
    return
})
```

Comment: How can I adapt this for parsing docx files?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is how you can read a file from S3 nodejs and keep it in memory without first writing the file to some location on disk. It can be used with a combination of S3 and AWS Lambda so that you don't have to write the files to some location on the Lambda.

Remember this processes is asynchronous.

```
   var params = {
        Bucket: "",
        Key: ""
    };

    var file = s3.getObject(params).createReadStream();
    var buffers = [];

    file.on('data', function (data) {
        buffers.push(data);
    });

    file.on('end', function () {
        var buffer = Buffer.concat(buffers);
        var workbook = xlsx.parse(buffer);
        console.log("workbook", workbook)
    });
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 9):

If you want use async/wait, here solution:

```
    const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
    const XLSX = require('xlsx');

    AWS.config.update({
      accessKeyId: AMAZON_ACCESS_KEY,
      secretAccessKey: AMAZON_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
    });

    // Get buffered file from s3    
    function getBufferFromS3(file, callback){
      const buffers = [];
      const s3 = new AWS.S3();
      const stream = s3.getObject({ Bucket: 'yor_buket', Key: file}).createReadStream();
      stream.on('data', data => buffers.push(data));
      stream.on('end', () => callback(null, Buffer.concat(buffers)));
      stream.on('error', error => callback(error));
    }

    // promisify read stream from s3
    function getBufferFromS3Promise(file) {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        getBufferFromS3(file, (error, s3buffer) => {
          if (error) return reject(error);
          return resolve(s3buffer);
        });
      });
    };

    // create workbook from buffer
    const buffer = await getBufferFromS3Promise(file);
    const workbook = XLSX.read(buffer);


    // If you want to send the workbook as a download to the api end point in node
    const fileName = "Categories.xlsx";
    res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=' + fileName);
    res.setHeader('Content-type', 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
    const wbout = XLSX.write(workbook, { bookType: 'xlsx', type: 'buffer'});
    res.send(new Buffer(wbout));
```

Comment: A closing `)` is missing in the `getBufferFromS3Promise` function from the last but one line.

Answer (score 4):

The `node-xlsx` module requires that the entire xlsx buffer be available. So you cannot pass it a `ReadStream` like you're currently doing. Try this method which entirely avoids writing to disk:

```
router.get('/process', (req, res) => {
    var fileName = 'https://some-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/some-excel-file.xlsx'
    https.get(fileName, response => {
        var chunks = []
        response.on('data', chunk => chunks.push(chunk))
        .on('end', () => {
            var book = xlsx.parse(Buffer.concat(chunks))
            book.forEach(sheet => console.log('sheet', sheet.name))
            res.status(200)          
        })
        .on('error', e => {
            res.status(500)
        })
    })
    return
})
```

Answer (score 3):

`fs.writeFile` is asynchronous.  The file won't be there till the call back is called.

https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_file_data_options_callback

```
fs.writeFile('message.txt', 'Hello Node.js', (err) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('It\'s saved!');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way of doing this is using [exceljs](https://github.com/exceljs/exceljs)

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const Excel = require('exceljs');

async function downloadFile(){
    AWS.config.update({
      accessKeyId: AMAZON_ACCESS_KEY,
      secretAccessKey: AMAZON_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
    });
       
    const s3 = new AWS.S3();
    const stream = await s3
     .getObject({ Bucket: 'yor_buket', Key: 'file_name'})
     .createReadStream();

    return stream;
}


async function loadWorkbook(stream){

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) = > {
        let rows = [];
        const workbook = new Excel.Workbook();
        
        workbook.xlsx.read(stream).then(function(workbook){

            const worksheet = workbook.getWorksheet('sheet_name');

            worksheet.eachRow({ includeEmpty: false}, function(row) {
                rows.push(row.values); 
            });
            resolve(rows);
        });
        
    });

}

async function loadFromS3(){
    const stream = await downloadFile();
    const dataRows = await loadWorkbook(stream);
    console.log(dataRows);
}
```

Comment: You need to "resolve" inside "then" block in "loadWorkbook" function.