# MySQL: Enforce an unique column without using an unique key

Tags: mysql

I have a column with data that exceeds MySQL's index length limit. Therefore, I can't use an unique key.

There's a solution here to the problem without using an unique key: [MySQL: Insert record if not exists in table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3164505/mysql-insert-record-if-not-exists-in-table)

However, in the comments, people are having issues with inserting the same value into multiple columns. In my case, a lot of my values are `0`, so I'll get duplicate values very often.

I'm using Node and `node-mysql` to access the database. I'm thinking I can have a variable that keeps track of all values that are currently being inserted. Before inserting, I check if the value is currently being inserting. If so, I'll wait until it finishes inserting, then continue execution as if the value was originally inserted. However, I feel like this will be very error prone.

Here's part of my table schema:

```
CREATE TABLE `links` (
  `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `url` varchar(2083) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_cs NOT NULL,
  `likes` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `tweets` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

ALTER TABLE `links`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD KEY `url` (`url`(50));
```

I cannot put an unique key on `url` because it can be 2083 bytes, which is over MySQL's key size limit. `likes` and `tweets` will often be `0`, so the linked solution will not work.

Is there another possible solution?

Comment: You could use a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger that checks whether the URL already exists, and signals an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you phrase your `INSERT` in a certain way, you can make use of `WHERE NOT EXISTS` to check first if the URL does not exist before completing the insert:

```
INSERT INTO links (`url`, `likes`, `tweets`) 
SELECT 'http://www.google.com', 10, 15 FROM DUAL
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
(SELECT 1 FROM links WHERE url='http://www.google.com');
```

This assumes that the `id` column is a primary key/auto increment, and MySQL will automatically assign a value to it.