# What does the "Unrecognised SQL statement" mean when I am trying to use IF NOT EXISTS?

Tags: php, mysql

I am getting the error on line 26 as shown by my browser.

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$database = "tut";

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database);

if (!$conn) {
    die("Database connection failed: ".mysqli_connect_error());
}
 if (isset($_POST['register']))
{
    $user = $_POST['username'];
    $pass = $_POST['password'];
    $pass2=$_POST['password1'];

    if(empty($username)||empty ($password)||empty($password1)){
        echo "Oops! Can't leave any field blank";
    }
    elseif($pass!=$pass2){
        echo "Passwords don't match";
    }   
    else{
        $phash = sha1(sha1($pass."salt")."salt");
        $sql=IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$user')
            INSERT INTO users (id, username, password) VALUES ('', '$user', '$phash')
        ELSE
            RAISERROR 'Username exists, please select a different one';
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    }
}
?>
```

Is this not a correct way of writing the IF NOT EXISTS statement. Also when I try to execute this directly in XAMPP I get Unrecognised SQL statement error!

Comment: Missing the THEN in the IF

Comment: We don't need a THEN @Haris

Comment: +1 to answer from @maytham-ɯɐɥʇʎɐɯ. P.S. please learn to use parameterized queries, because your code is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: Yes I have solved the issue, and I have understood my mistake I was combining SQL wid PHP code ..thanks for the help , I didn't do it exactly as you said , but I used what you meant!! @maytham-ɯɐɥʇʎɐɯ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how to do it, I have test it and it works:

```
$sql = "
    INSERT INTO users (username, password)
    SELECT * FROM (SELECT '$user', '$phash') AS tmp
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = '$user'
    ) LIMIT 1;
";
```

This solution is inspired from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3164505/mysql-insert-record-if-not-exists-in-table).

The problem is that you can not combine PHP and MySQL statement like you did, you need to encapsulate all MySQL statements in quote `"`.

What comes `RAISERROR`, it is not MySQL function, it belongs to Microsoft.

You could easily make php if statement that checks if `$sql` contain valid username and return your message. That part is left to your fantasy.

XAMPP has no thing to do with the error, it just a software that provides an Apache and MySQL installation for Windows.

> Note: P.S. please learn to use parameterized queries, because your
>   code is vulnerable to SQL injection. thanks to @BillKarwin for mentioning this.