# MySQL 5.67 - Inserting values if not exists in table not working

Tags: mysql

I have a table with no primary keys and two columns. When the table is empty this query should generate a record and when this record already exists it should not.

```
INSERT INTO traffic (traffic_time, traffic_amount) 
SELECT '13:00:00', '24' FROM traffic
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM traffic WHERE traffic_time = '13:00:00' AND 
traffic_amount = '24')
```

However when running this no rows are inserted even if there are no duplicates.

I tried using other answers like:

```
INSERT INTO traffic (traffic_time, traffic_amount)
SELECT '13:00:00','24'
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM traffic WHERE traffic_time = '13:00:00' AND 
traffic_amount = '24') LIMIT 1
```

But this one gives me a "Error Code 1064 SQL Syntax Error" even though it is syntactically correct.

How can I resolve this issue without adding a primary key?

---

*Note: I have looked at similar S.O. threads but am unable to resolve this issue. These answers are from those threads*

Comment: Did you try running the select statement alone?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL: Insert record if not exists in table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3164505/mysql-insert-record-if-not-exists-in-table)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following [link from my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3164505/mysql-insert-record-if-not-exists-in-table)...

```
INSERT INTO traffic (t1, t2)
  SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT
          '24' as tmp1,
          '24' as tmp2) as tmp
  WHERE NOT EXISTS(
      SELECT t1, t2
      FROM traffic
      WHERE t1 = '24' AND
            t2 = '24'
  )
  LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work if there are columns with the same values. e.g. if I change your code to: https://pastebin.com/nVpeLGB1 it gives error code 1060

Comment: Is there any way to modify your query to cater to this?

Comment: Whoops I linked the wrong one originally. Both numbers should be 24

Comment: Query modified, take it