# MySQL - Insert only when certain value does not exist

Tags: mysql

Let's say I have this table

```
ID  |   Name    |   Hobby
---------------------------
1   |   Alex    |   fishing
2   |   Alex    |   soccer
3   |   Nick    |   bike
4   |   George  |   hike
```

`ID` - is unique. `Hobby` - is NOT unique (need to keep it as non-unique)

Inserting a record:

```
INSERT INTO my_table (ID, Name, Hobby) VALUES ('5', 'Christina', 'bike')
```

How to modify the query, if I need to insert the record if `bike` value does not exist at all in `Hobby` column?

Anotherwords:

- `VALUES ('5', 'Christina', 'bike')` - would NOT be inserted as `3 | Nick | bike` exists
- `VALUES ('5', 'Christina', 'cooking')` would be inserted as `cooking` is not present in `Hobby` column at all.

Having existing database with thousands of records, there is a risk that there are duplicates already in Hobby...

But from now on.. when adding new records, I want to avoid adding if already exists..

Thank you.

Comment: `where not exists (Select * from my_table B where hobby = 'bike' and A.hobby=b.hobby)`. and alias the outer my_table as A.

Comment: Um, that's what UNIQUE does?!?!?!?!? But you can emulate this odd behaviour with a join

Comment: @xQbert: is it possible to do that with `VALUES` instead of select?

Comment: @Strawberry could you give a concrete example?

Comment: Perhaps. If you provided CREATE and INSERT statements (https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution could be changing hobby column to unique. This way you will force your database to only insert unique hobbies. Another solution could be using triggers fore before insert / update.

Comment: @ihtus Then the  solution could be using triggers. I used triggers for checking on duplicates before inserting and before updating.

Comment: I expected another more elegant solution.. anything without triggers?

Comment: @ihtus could you explain why you do not want to use triggers ?

Comment: @Mjh: To project on the simple DB example here... I have an existing DB (thousands record) and there is a risk that I have dublicates in Hobby.. But from now on.. I need to alter it considering that I won't add duplicates

Comment: @ihtus if you do not want any duplicates anymore you have to use triggers. This will prevent the database to insert duplicates from insert and updates. Still have no idea why you do not want to use triggers.

Answer (score -2):

Based on [MySQL: Insert record if not exists in table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3164505/mysql-insert-record-if-not-exists-in-table)

But with some corrections (to fix the duplicate errors)

The following query works for me.

```
INSERT INTO my_table (ID, Name, Hobby)
SELECT * FROM (SELECT '5' AS ID, 'Christina' AS Name, 'cooking'  AS Hobby) AS tmp
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT name FROM table_listnames WHERE Hobby= 'cooking'
) LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: This is incorrect. You're prone to concurrency. Another process can insert the same row. The only way for your desired feature to work is to place a unique constraint over several columns. Since your columns are text-based, the proper solution is to use a trigger, concatenate textual values, hash them and insert the hash along with the data. Place the `unique` constraint over that one column and you won't have issues. Or, you can use this concurrency-prone falsy solution.

Comment: @Mjh: To project on the simple DB example here... I have an existing DB (thousands record) and there is a risk that I have dublicates in Hobby.. But from now on.. I need to alter it considering that I won't add duplicates any more.. what is unclear here?

Comment: @Mjh: I am ok with the above query, I don't have any other processed that will alter the table