# if file not exist insert in one table and take other values to insert in other table

Tags: mysql, database

i have the following database  2 tables with `PK_Hash_ID` in `md5` table and `FK_Hash_ID` in `Files` table.

Lets say for example I need to insert new record,

first I have to check if its  `MD5` exists  in `MD5 table`, if not add it to the `MD5 table` and `Files table`, 
however if its already there on `MD5` just take that `Hash_ID` and insert

it into `files` with some other values taken from the `Parameters` such `File_name`, `Parent_Path`, `DataType`,etc

> Consider that the solution must be a Stored Procedure, That takes parameters

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL: Insert record if not exists in table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3164505/mysql-insert-record-if-not-exists-in-table)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved using `IF EXISTS`  statement .

```
 BEGIN

If EXISTS (SELECT Hash_ID from MD5 Where MD5Hash = MD5Hash1)
Then
SELECT @H := Hash_ID from md5 where MD5Hash = MD5Hash1;
INSERT INTO MD5 Where MD5Hash = @H (Counter) values (+1);
INSERT INTO files (Hash_ID , File_Name , Path, Parent_Path , DataType )
values ( @H, FileName,Path, ParentPath, Type );
ELSE  
Insert INTO md5 (MD5Hash, Counter ) VALUES (MD5Hash1,+1);
SELECT @H := Hash_ID from md5 where MD5Hash = MD5Hash1;


INSERT INTO files (Hash_ID , File_Name , Path, Parent_Path , DataType )
values ( @H, FileName,Path, ParentPath, Type );
End IF ;
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Make md5HASH column unique in md5 table, By which you can be sure that there will never be any duplicate entry in it. Try to insert each MD5HASH in md5 table, If query fails check for the error type if error is because of unique key constraint, that means the HASH already exists if no error HASH will be inserted into table md5.
Sample code would be like

```
$sql = "insert into md5 values (null,'file_name',$hash)";
$result = mysqli_query($sql);
if( mysql_errno() == 1062) {
    //write the code which you want to execute in case of hash already existing 
} else {
   //write the code where hash doesn't existed earlier, but now it has already added in database. No need to add again.
}
```

I hope this helped.

Comment: in any case the files_tbl is going to have a new record its only the md5_tbl that i need to make sure nothing is dublicated for example i have (file_name , Prent_Path, etc ) first iam going to check md5 tbl if exist if its already exist take that md5_Id inserto the rest of the data in the Files_tbl ,, in other case if this md5hash not existed add it to the md5_tbl and then take the id again and insert the data to the files_tbl

Comment: Just make the md5Hash column unique. MySql will take care of the rest.You will have the value of HASH in all the cases so there is no need to select it from the database.

Comment: ill try that for sure

Comment: Mark the answer as useful , If it helped you.