# How to check if row exists using sqlx?

Tags: mysql, go, sqlx

Using [sqlx](https://github.com/jmoiron/sqlx), I'd like to know query MySql database to know whether a query on MySql returns empty rows:

So following [this](https://github.com/jmoiron/sqlx/issues/375), I came up with

```
var result model.Post
err := database.SQL.Get(&result, "SELECT * FROM post WHERE post_id=? AND user_id=? LIMIT 1", postID, userID)
if err == sql.ErrNoRows { 
    log.Println(err)
    log.Println("post not found")
} else { 
    log.Println("post found")
}
```

But I always get `post found`, despite the fact that there is no row.

What could be wrong here and how can I fix it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I want to check if record exist and if not exist then i want to insert that record to database using golang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49449087/i-want-to-check-if-record-exist-and-if-not-exist-then-i-want-to-insert-that-reco)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If row found err will be nil

Here is working example:

```
var result model.Post
err := database.SQL.Get(&result, "SELECT * FROM post WHERE post_id=? AND user_id=? LIMIT 1", postID, userID)

switch err {
case nil:
    log.Printf("user found: %+v\n", user)
case sql.ErrNoRows:
    log.Println("user NOT found, no error")
default:
    log.Printf("error: %s\n", err)
}
```