# Normalize data before loading to database or use database?

Tags: mysql, database-design, relational-database

I have some data which I want to add to an existing mysql database. The new data may have entries, which are already saved on DB. Since some of my columns are unique, I get, as expected, an ER_DUP_ENTRY error.

### Bulk Insert

Let's say I want to use following statement to save "A", "B" and "C" in a column  `names` of table `mytable` and "A" is already saved there.

```sql
insert into mytable (names) values ("A"), ("B"), ("C");
```

Is there a way to directly use `bulk insert` to save "B" and "C" while ignoring "A"? Or do I have to build an `insert` statement for every new row? This leads to another question:

### Normalize Data

Should I assure not to upload duplicate entries **before** the actual `insert` statement? In my case I would need to `select` the data from database, eliminate duplicates and then perform the above seen `insert`. Or is that a task which is supposed to be done by a database?

Comment: Most often, I believe this is handled by the database server. Take a look at this stack question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3164505/3148109

Comment: If I get it right, I can't use bulk insert for that task? Because the way it is shown there, it checks for every entry if it already exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have UNIQUE constraints that are blocking import, you have a few ways you can work around that:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO mytable ...
```

If any individual rows violate a UNIQUE constraint, they are skipped. Other rows are inserted.

```
REPLACE INTO mytable ...
```

If any rows violate a UNIQUE constraint, DELETE the existing row, then INSERT the new row. Keep in mind side-effects of doing this, like if you have foreign keys that cascade on delete referencing the deleted row. Or if the INSERT generates a new auto-increment id.

```
INSERT INTO mytable ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...
```

More flexibility. This does not delete the original row, but allows you to set new values for any columns you choose on a case by case basis. See also my answer to ["INSERT IGNORE" vs "INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/548541/insert-ignore-vs-insert-on-duplicate-key-update/548570#548570)

If you want to use bulk-loading with `mysqlimport` or the SQL statement equivalent `LOAD DATA INFILE`, there are options that match the INSERT IGNORE or REPLACE solutions, but not the INSERT...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE solution.

Read docs for more information:

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert.html
- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replace.html
- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html
- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqlimport.html
- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html

Answer (score 0):

In some situations, I like to do this:

1. `LOAD DATA` into a temp table
2. Clean up the data
3. Normalize as needed. (2 SQLs per column that needs normalizing -- [*details*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/staging_table#normalization))
4. Augment Summary table(s) (`INSERT .. ON DUPLICATE KEY .. SELECT x, y, count(*), sum(z), .. GROUP BY x,y`)
5. Copy clean data from temp table to real table(s) ("Fact" table).  (`INSERT [IGNORE] .. SELECT [DISTINCT] ..` or IODKU with `SELECT`.)

More on Normalizing:

- I do it outside any transactions.  There are multiple reasons why this is better.
- At worst (as a result of other failures), I occasionally throw an unused entry in the normalization table.  No big deal.
- No burning of `AUTO_INCREMENT` ids (except in edge cases).
- Very fast.

Since `REPLACE` is a `DELETE` plus `INSERT` it is almost guaranteed to be worse than IODKU.  However, both burn ids when the rows exist.

If at all possible, do not "loop" through the rows; instead find SQL statements to handle them all at once.

Depending on the details, de-dup in step 2 (if lots of dups) or in step 5 (dups are uncommon).