# Check before adding the data into table in mysql database

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench, mysql-python, mysql-error-1064

I am trying to insert data in table emp_master where token_no and vehicle_no is available, I am using mentioned below query to add and check the record

```
insert into emp_master (token_no, vehicle_no) values (1234,12345) where not exists (select * from emp_master where vehicle_no = '12345');
```

but whenever I am trying this then error comes in as

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'where not exists (select * from emp_master where vehicle_no = '12345')' at line 1
```

The suggestion will be helpful

Comment: You cannot have WHERE in INSERT STATEMENT. You need to create before insert trigger and check everything there. Or use FK to prevent inserting record that is related to non-existing identifiers.

Comment: This link might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3164505/mysql-insert-record-if-not-exists-in-table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to have this check in your insert statement, you can structure it like this:

**SQL Fiddle**: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d3dd77/1

```
insert into emp_master (token_no, vehicle_no) 
select 1234, 12345
from dual
where not exists (select * from emp_master where vehicle_no = '12345');
```

Another way to do this on any DBMS:

**[DB Fiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=5015f937ee6a200781746553714edec6)**

```
insert into emp_master (token_no, vehicle_no) 
select token_no, vehicle_no
from (
select 1234 token_no, 12345 vehicle_no
) rec
where not exists (select * from emp_master where vehicle_no = rec.vehicle_no);
```

Answer (score 0):

Put a [`UNIQUE` constraint](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/constraint-primary-key.html) on the `vehicle_no` column, and then insert the data with no `WHERE` clause. Instead, handle the exception if it fails.