# insert row if not exist in database

Tags: python, mysql, mariadb

Hello how can i do to insert uniq rows without duplicate.

```
cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tab1 (id varchar(36) primary key, cap1 VARCHAR(4), cap2 varchar(55), cap3 int(6), Version VARCHAR(4));")
id = uuid.uuid1()
id = str(id)
cursor.execute("INSERT IGNORE INTO tab1 (id, cap1, cap2, cap3, Version) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s )", (vals))
```

[image: caption_tab1]

I should not insert the third row while is the same as first row.
Hope im clear .
Thank you in advance,

Comment: https://chartio.com/resources/tutorials/how-to-insert-if-row-does-not-exist-upsert-in-mysql/

Comment: @Zeljka thank you for your response. Unfortunately i saw this link and was not able to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `uuid()` will always give a unique identifier and since `id` is a **primary key**, the row is getting inserted with duplicate values except for id column which is different always.

I think this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3164505/mysql-insert-record-if-not-exists-in-table) might answer your question or else, create a [unique index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/635937/how-do-i-specify-unique-constraint-for-multiple-columns-in-mysql) on columns that you want to be unique.

Let me know if it helps!!

Comment: Thank you for you link.. have i don't know how to do in my case. Notice that the example that i have given is a sample of my data .. i cant also verify evry column and check if value exist . (cauz i have in total 90 columns in my database). Please if you have an idea don"t hesitate.

Comment: Maybe i can create something like Uniq key of all fileds except id?

Comment: Yeah, that's right!! As I mentioned in my answer, you can create a unique index on columns that you want to be unique. You can use this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/635937/how-do-i-specify-unique-constraint-for-multiple-columns-in-mysql to create a unique index.

Comment: i want to leave id as primary key of the table and then create another unique key as combinasion of the other columns.? Can i do that do you think?

Comment: Yeah, you can create multiple unique indexes leaving id as a primary key. You can use this link: https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-unique/ to create a unique key.

Comment: @charles No Problem!!