# Insert into table column if entry does not exist

Tags: java, xml, liquibase

In Liquibase I would like to insert values if the values are not already set. With a normal insert I suspect that the inserted value will overwrite the previous value if the value is already there. I want it to ony insert if it does not exist. Can this be done?

Right now I am using the insert as seen below:

```
<insert tableName="state">
  <column name="name" value="fooFoo"/>
  <column name="enabled" valueBoolean="true"/>
</insert>
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The proper way to do this is to use `preConditions`.

There's an `<sqlCheck>` [preCondition](https://docs.liquibase.com/concepts/advanced/preconditions.html?Highlight=sqlCheck).

> **sqlCheck**
>
> Executes an SQL string and checks the returned value. The SQL must
>   return a single row with a single value. To check numbers of rows, use
>   the “count” SQL function. To check for ranges of values, perform the
>   check in the SQL and return a value that can be easily compared
>   against.
>
> `<sqlCheck  expectedResult="1">SELECT COUNT(1) FROM pg_tables WHERE TABLENAME = 'myRequiredTable'</sqlCheck>`

With it your changeSet will look like this:

```
<changeSet id="foo" author="bar">
    <preConditions onFail="MARK_RAN">
        <sqlCheck expectedResult="0">
            SELECT COUNT(*) FROM state WHERE name='fooFoo' AND enabled=true;
        </sqlCheck>
    </preConditions>
    <insert tableName="state">
      <column name="name" value="fooFoo"/>
      <column name="enabled" valueBoolean="true"/>
    </insert>
</changeSet>
```

Comment: If you remove the "AND enabled=true" then it becomes better. The logic should be: if "fooFoo" does not exist then add "fooFoo" and "true", else do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the below question:

[MySQL: Insert record if not exists in table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3164505/mysql-insert-record-if-not-exists-in-table)

just use < sql > tag to do that in Liquibase.

Hope this helps.

Edit:

< sql >

INSERT INTO state(name, enabled)
SELECT * FROM (SELECT 'fooFoo', 'true') AS tmp
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT name FROM state WHERE name = 'fooFoo'
) LIMIT 1

< /sql >

Comment: I am not sure I understand exactly how to use the tag in Liquibase. Could you write out the whole answer, please? Maybe an explanation to that would be good.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question - you've given an answer specific to MySQL, but OP hasn't said what database they are using. Presumably, something that works on all databases supported by Liquibase  is being requested...

Comment: You literally meant the SQL tag. I saw some other "tag" at another place and thought you meant that. I used your suggestion and modified it. Copy it into your answer and I will mark it as answered. Also give me a thread point, please. 

INSERT INTO state(name, enabled)
SELECT * FROM (SELECT 'fooFoo' AS name, 1 AS enabled) AS tmp
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
SELECT name FROM state WHERE name = 'fooFoo') LIMIT 1;

And yes, this is a mySQL, which I did not mention. ;)

Comment: Yes, StackOverflow edited out the SQL tag, I had to provide spaces in them to display them.