# INSERT INTO Statement via previous data MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to create new data in a table based on a previous data.

The table contains 11 columns.
And the following SQL statement should be executed.

Where the column **isOnPause** returns true and the column **endDate** contains **'%10:00%'**
then
**INSERT INTO table** almost the same data with **endDate="" AND a new ID generated for each row**.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3164505/mysql-insert-record-if-not-exists-in-table

Comment: Self-insertions like `INSERT INTO FOO ... (SELECT ... FROM FOO WHERE ...)` are not possible, Use a [temporary table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-temporary-table.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following syntax.
NB the syntax `endDate like  '%10:00%'` works in MySQL 8 but is not accepted in MySQL 5 so I have used an explicit `CAST(endDate AS CHAR(20))` which works in both.

> ```
> create table t(
> id int auto_increment primary key,
> isOnPause tinyint,
> endDate datetime,
> otherCol varchar(10));
> insert into t (isOnPause, endDate,otherCol) values
> (1,'2022-03-29 10:00:00','other 1'),
> (0,'2022-03-29 10:00:00','other 2'),
> (1,'2022-03-29 11:00:00','other 3'),
> (0,'2022-03-29 11:00:00','other 4');
> ```

> ```
> select * from t 
> where isOnPause 
> and endDate like  '%10:00%' ;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | isOnPause | endDate             | otherCol
> -: | --------: | :------------------ | :-------
>  1 |         1 | 2022-03-29 10:00:00 | other 1
> ```

> ```
> insert into t (isOnPause, endDate,otherCol)
> select isOnPause,null,otherCol from t 
> where isOnPause 
> and CAST(endDate AS CHAR(20))  like  '%10:00%' ;
> ```

> ```
> select * from t;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | isOnPause | endDate             | otherCol
> -: | --------: | :------------------ | :-------
>  1 |         1 | 2022-03-29 10:00:00 | other 1 
>  2 |         0 | 2022-03-29 10:00:00 | other 2 
>  3 |         1 | 2022-03-29 11:00:00 | other 3 
>  4 |         0 | 2022-03-29 11:00:00 | other 4 
>  5 |         1 | null                | other 1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=f8476a706fec8b7f2d32ad9d9dcccc31)*