# Insert New Row id to another table and also Insert record if not exists in table 2, to avoid duplicate entries

Tags: mysql, database

### **Table:1**

| id | image | cat id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 7 | asdf | 1 |
| 15 | jhgfv | 1 |
| 17 | dfgh | 2 |
| 19 | rtyu | 2 |
| 21 | fghjk | 2 |

### **Table:2**

| id | image | cat id | Column E | Column F | Column G | Column H | Column I |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

Here I had two tables and from table 1, I want to fetch all 3 column's data and insert them into Table 2

I want to Insert this data with the trigger in MySQL.

### AND I WANT Table 2 LIKE ...

| id | image | cat id | Column E | Column F | Column G | Column H | Column I |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 7 | asdf | 1 | 'Default Value' | 'Default Value' | 'Default Value' | 'Default Value' | 'Default Value' |
| 15 | jhgfv | 1 | 'Default Value' | 'Default Value' | 'Default Value' | 'Default Value' | 'Default Value' |
| 17 | dfgh | 2 | 'Default Value' | 'Default Value' | 'Default Value' | 'Default Value' | 'Default Value' |
| 19 | rtyu | 2 | 'Default Value' | 'Default Value' | 'Default Value' | 'Default Value' | 'Default Value' |
| 21 | fghjk | 2 | 'Default Value' | 'Default Value' | 'Default Value' | 'Default Value' | 'Default Value' |

I TRIED :

```
INSERT INTO `table 2` (`id`, `cat_id`, `image`, `Column C`, `Column D`, `Column E`, `Column F`, `Column G`, `Column H`, `Column I`) VALUES
(NEW.ID, NEW.cat_id, NEW.image, '', '', '','', '', 'open', 'open', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 0, '', 0, '', '', '', '', '', 0, '', 0);

HERE >>>>>>>>>   ''  <<<<< IS THE DEFAULT VALUE
```

But this gives and duplicate values.

To avoid duplicate value I also try this: [MySQL: Insert record if not exists in table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3164505/mysql-insert-record-if-not-exists-in-table)

```
INSERT INTO `table 2` (`id`, `cat_id`, `image`, `Column C`, `Column D`, `Column E`, `Column F`, `Column G`, `Column H`, `Column I`) VALUES
(NEW.ID, NEW.cat_id, NEW.image, '', '', '','', '', 'open', 'open', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 0, '', 0, '', '', '', '', '', 0, '', 0);

HERE \>\>\>\>\>\>\>\>\>   ''  \<\<\<\<\< IS THE DEFAULT VALUE
```

[To avoid duplicate value I also try this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3164505/mysql-insert-record-if-not-exists-in-table)

Comment: so why didn't the linked question work for you? have you just tried adding a unique index?

Comment: I can't understand my query so it gives me an error

Comment: please help me......

Comment: I want to insert new data remove duplicates with trigger in mysql

Answer (score 0):

If `id` in `table2` is a primary key or an unique key, you already can't add the same `id` twice but it will complain about duplicate if you insert it.

You can use `INSERT IGNORE INTO` to tell MySQL to simply ignore duplicate in this case.

PS: You should add your tables schemas in the question